# A include_template Question

Tags: plugins, template-include

Right now I am building virtual pages on a wordpress install. I use the include_template hook to add some logic that checks for a 404 page & some regex to look for a specific pattern.

This seems horribly inefficient. If my plugin is doing this, and other plugins are doing this, arn't we all just adding tons of code to be parsed every single time a page loads on the website? What happens when my plugins grows enormously. This system of hooks is terrible.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Try to narrow the times when your plugin runs, if you can't because your plugin have to run on every page load, I don't understand the question... Also *"What happens when my plugins grows enormously"* don't let your plugin grow enormously... PS the nae of the hook is 'template_include' not 'include_template'.

Comment: Misunderstand of, or misuse of, hooks doesn't make the system itself terrible.

Comment: So I don't know that you tried to answer the question. Is this the default way wordpress intended to use when creating dynamic pages not in the database (virtual pages)?